# Angular 7 add custom src for script tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

I am using angluar cli to build my app.

Currently its building the app in dist folder

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Admin</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.aa8ce79f832f8715c04d.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root>
  </app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.d981c7f14a84cffbe02a.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.c914ea4c8f6edd6e6f45.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.b5ea1a3cf9f89977f873.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.ebfc576e2cbf5f6d553e.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I would like to customize all src path to have **/app** appended & look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/runtime.d981c7f14a84cffbe02a.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `deploy-url` parameter when building your app

```
ng build --prod  --deploy-url /app/
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to prepend rather than append.
Try changing your base href value so that all relative paths start from the app folder
From:

```
<base href="/">
```

```
To:
<base href="./">
```

Comment: It's not about app folder, I am building angular to a springboot jar. It has a context of "/app" to it. In this case when I load index.html, the next GET to my server will be localhost:8080/runtime.js. This will be 404, it should be localhost:8080/app/runtime.js